# The value of this series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i+n}{i+n+m}\frac{x^{i+n+m}}{i!}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am trying to calculate the value of this series
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i+n}{i+n+m}\frac{x^{i+n+m}}{i!}$$

If we get the derivative with respect to $x$, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i+n}{i!}x^{i+n+m-1}=e^xx^{n+m-1}(x+n)$$
Now if we integrate the expression on the right hand side, we have
\begin{align}
\int e^xx^{n+m-1}(x+n)~ dx &= \int e^xx^{n+m-1}x~ dx + \int e^xx^{n+m-1}n~ dx \\
&=(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\Gamma(n+m-1,-x) - n(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\Gamma(n+m,-x) \\
&=(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\left[\Gamma(n+m-1,-x) - n\Gamma(n+m,-x)\right]
\end{align}
So I think
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i+n}{i+n+m}\frac{x^{i+n+m}}{i!}=(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\left[\Gamma(n+m-1,-x) - n\Gamma(n+m,-x)\right]$$

I wanted to double-check my calculations so I used *Mathematica* for the first series and the answer I get is
$$(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\left[n\Gamma(n+m, 0, -x) - \Gamma(n+m+1, 0, -x)\right]$$
where according to its documentation, $\Gamma(a,z_0,z_1) = \Gamma(a,z_0) - \Gamma(a,z_1)$.

So did I calculate the value of the first series incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x = 0$, then the sum is trivially $0$.  For real-valued nonzero $x$, the expression $(-x)^{-(n+m)} x^{n+m}$ simplifies to $(-1)^{n+m}$.  When taking this into consideration, the difference between the first calculation and the second is $(-1)^{m+n} m \Gamma(m+n)$, which demonstrates their equivalence up to a constant of integration with respect to $x$.

Comment: Thank you. So does this mean that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i+n}{i+n+m}\frac{x^{i+n+m}}{i!}=(-x)^{-(n+m)}x^{n+m}\left[\Gamma(n+m-1,-x) - n\Gamma(n+m,-x)\right]+(-1)^{n+m}m\Gamma(n+m)$? I'm confused because I don't know what the correct value of the series is. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: It is $$(-1)^{-(n+m)} \left( \Gamma(n+m-1, -x) - n \Gamma(n+m, -x) - m \Gamma(n+m)\right).$$